# Django Deep Linking render with #tag

Tags: django, tabs, django-templates, deep-linking

I am trying to Deep Link tabs with Dango by adding the #panel1 at the end.

This would be the template needed:

```
template = "charts/chart1.html#panel1"
return render ( request, template, context )
```

But obviously Django can not find that template once I add the hashtag.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thank You.

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html

Comment: I think you have to specify **#panel1** on the template itself and here only the template name required.

Comment: What do you think adding the # would do here? This is about rendering a template, not navigating to a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a javascript guy, but I got this to work.  Maybe it can be improved?

I set the tab position inside the View:

```
tab = '#panel2v'
```

then call the Foundation JS.

```
$('[data-tabs]').eq(0).foundation('selectTab', $('{{tab}}'));
```

I hope this helps?  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Anything after the # ( hashbang ) is not even sent to Django webserver. You have to do the logic in your Javascript. Please consider add all your chart code to `charts/chart.html` and I think adding `tabs` class enought for the toggle.

views

```
template = "charts/chart.html"
return render ( request, template, context )
```

html

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a data-tabs-target="panel2" href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

But also if you're looking for the JS reference [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html#javascript-reference)